# Showing Image in Different Position and Size in Relative Layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I am able to view recycle view image in relative layout but its showing images like fixed table row.Layout doesn't have look and feel in design. I am looking something like each image in different size and in different position. Any suggestion is appreciated.
I have added layout and adapter class below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="161dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/light_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="301dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Image"
                android:layout_width="349dp"
                android:layout_height="109dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Name"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-185dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="153dp"
                android:scaleType="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                android:layout_marginRight="-185dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Name" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Adapter**

```
{
      override fun getItemCount(): Int
    {
        return list.size
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder
    {
        val view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_row_food_one,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)
    {
        holder.bindItem(list[position],fragment)
    }
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        fun bindItem(test:TestDetail?,fragment: FragmentOne)=with(itemView)
        {
            var testImage: ImageView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.testImage)
            Picasso.get().load(test!!.itemImage).into(testImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the main problem you've faced? Does each image have different sizes?

Comment: I post my answer have a look at it.

Comment: All the images are same size but I am looking for images in different position.

Comment: You can use constraint Layout to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Use **Linear Layout** it give as per your look and feel in design because it's have a fix position in screen but in Relative Layout it can relative to other component so,it position is not fix.

So,I prefer to use Linear Layout instead of Relative Layout.

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.